# How To Specify Which Constructor Gets Called for a Member Field Object?

Tags: c++, constructor

If I have some class, and within that class I have a custom made Queue object that I have written, and my class def looks like this:

```
class Parser
{
    public:
        Parser();
    private:
        Queue<char> Q;
};
```

And `class Queue` has a default constructor as well as a constructor that takes a single int parameter to specify its capacity, how do I tell the Parser class that when it instantiates the Q field it should fire the constructor that takes a parameter (so it can have a larger capacity) rather than fire the default constructor (which has a pretty small capacity) ? I've looked this up but I am having a hard time finding an answer that doesn't revolve around inheritance and parent class constructors. Thanks!

Also, I have tried replacing `Queue<char> Q` with `Queue<char> Q(100)` but the compiler complains about this.

Comment: It's not QT that complains, it's your compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor implementation of Parser use the initializer list...

```
Parser::Parser()
:Q(10) ///example of initializing to capacity 10
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
Parser() : Q(100) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is in the member-initialization-list where you choose the constructor:

- If you want to invoke the default constructor, then do this:

  ```
  Parser() : Q() {} //calls the default constructor
  ```

  Since you don't pass any argument, then the above is same as:

  ```
   Parser() {} //Q is also constructed invoking the default constructor
  ```

  Before entering into the body of `Parser` constructor, `Q` is *fully* constructed by invoking the default constructor.
- If you want to invoke the other constructor, do this:

  ```
  Parser() : Q(10) {} //calls the other constructor
  ```

  This is what you want. In such cases, you usually want to pass the size to `Parser` which then does this:

  ```
  Parser(int size) : Q(size) {} //calls the other constructor
  ```

In C++11, you can do this in the declaration itself as:

```
class Parser
{
     //...
     Queue<char> Q(10); //C++11 only
};
```